# How to add react-hooks on the ready site?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I know how to add only react and react-Dom , but if we will write some text on the react-hooks as the code:
***const state = useState('name')***

We will receive  an error :
***Uncaught ReferenceError: useState is not defined***

ITS ISNT APP , Its just a ready site i know how to add hooks on the app , but dont know how on the ready site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to import useState from React as shown on https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

````
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}```
````